# Rename database field within array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to change a few database fields in my backend controller before returning the object to the frontend.

Currently, I am doing it in the front end like this with my returned object:

```
       for (let contribution of contributions) {
          contribution["title"] = "You Added One"
          contribution["launchName"] = contribution.name
          contribution["launchId"] = contribution._id
          contribution["date"] = contribution.addedAt
          contribution["content"] = contribution.description
        }
```

But I am now trying to do this work in the backend using Mongo.

This is my controller:

```
const Launch = require('../models/launch')
const User = require('../models/user')
async function getRecentActivityByUserId (req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params

  const user = await User.findOne({ userId }).lean() || []

  const contributions = await Launch.find({ _id: { $in: user.contributions } })

  return res.status(200).send(contributions.reverse())
}
```

So this correctly returns an object to the frontend but I still need to change the database field names.

So I tried this:

```
async function getRecentActivityByUserId (req, res) {
  let recents = []
  const { userId } = req.params

  const user = await User.findOne({ userId }).lean() || []

  const contributions = await Launch.find({ _id: { $in: user.contributions } }).aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            plans: {
                $map:{
                    input: "$launch",
                    as: "l",
                    in: {
                        title: "You Added One",
                        launchName: "$$l.name",
                        launchId: "$$l._id",
                        date: "$$l.addedAt",
                        content: "$$l.description",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "launch"
    }
])

  return res.status(200).send(contributions.reverse())
}
```

The above throws an error saying that I `.aggregrate` is not a function on `.find`. Even if I remove the `.find`, the object returned is just an empty array so I'm obviously not aggregating correctly.

How can I combine `.find` with `.aggregate` and what is wrong with my `.aggregate` function??

I also tried combining aggregate with find like this and get the error `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`:

```
  const contributions = await Launch.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
      _id: { $in: user.contributions }
      },
        $addFields: {
            plans: {
                $map:{
                    input: "$launch",
                    as: "l",
                    in: {
                        title: "You Added a Kayak Launch",
                        launchName: "$$l.name",
                        launchId: "$$l._id",
                        date: "$$l.addedAt",
                        content: "$$l.description",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "launch"
    }
])
```

EDIT: Just realized that I have the word `plans` in the aggregate function and that is not relevant to my code. I copied this code from elsewhere so not sure what the value should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is the solution:

```
async function getRecentActivityByUserId (req, res) {
  let recents = []
  const { userId } = req.params

  const user = await User.findOne({ userId }).lean() || []

  const contributions = await Launch.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: { $in: user.contributions }
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        title: "You Added One" ,
        launchName: "$name",
        launchId: "$_id",
        date: "$addedAt",
        content: "$description"
      }
    }
 ])
  if(contributions) {
    recents = recents.concat(contributions);
  }

  return res.status(200).send(recents.reverse())
}
```

Comment: Yeah it looks like the error from the last attempt in your question was mostly just syntax (missing some curly brackets).  If it's helpful - you could check out the `$lookup` aggregation stage. It would allow you to combine the `findOne()` and subsequent `aggregate()` into a single call to the database to avoid an extra round trip. Glad you got it figured out regardless!

Comment: You're right about the extra trip around. Do you happen to have any examples or know how to combine my `findOne` with my `Launch.aggregate`?

Comment: Too long for a comment, so added an answer with a bit more details and a mongo playground link

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem from the question was a small syntax error which has been noted and corrected in [the self-reported answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73926238/20042973).

I noted in the comments there that the current approach of issuing two separate operations (a `findOne()` followed by an `aggregate()` that uses the results) could be simplified into a single query to the database. The important thing here is that you will `$match` against the first collection (`users` or whatever the collection name is in your environment) and then use `$lookup` to perform the "match" against the subsequent `launches` collection.

[Here is a playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KdXsI-QBRx7) demonstrating the basic approach. Adjust as needed to the specifics of your environment.